Getting Error: trying to setup connection with GCP managed kafka service with Debezium using docker via compose.yaml?
[org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,017 INFO   ||  Retrieved token with principal sub   [org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.unsecured.OAuthBearerUnsecuredLoginCallbackHandler]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,026 INFO   ||  Successfully logged in.   [org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,040 INFO   ||  [Principal=:sub]: Expiring credential re-login thread started.   [org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,079 INFO   ||  [Principal=sub]: Expiring credential valid from Fri Dec 20 18:01:23 UTC 2024 to Fri Dec 20 19:01:23 UTC 2024   [org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,081 INFO   ||  [Principal=:sub]: Expiring credential re-login sleeping until: Fri Dec 20 18:51:08 UTC 2024   [org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,353 INFO   ||  These configurations '[sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url, config.storage.topic, rest.advertised.host.name, group.id, status.storage.topic, rest.advertised.port, task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms, rest.host.name, plugin.path, offset.flush.timeout.ms, config.storage.replication.factor, offset.flush.interval.ms, rest.port, key.converter.schemas.enable, status.storage.replication.factor, value.converter.schemas.enable, offset.storage.replication.factor, offset.storage.topic, value.converter, key.converter]' were supplied but are not used yet.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,357 INFO   ||  Kafka version: 3.8.0   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,358 INFO   ||  Kafka commitId: 771b9576b00ecf5b   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:24,358 INFO   ||  Kafka startTimeMs: 1734717684357   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,038 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Failed authentication with bootstrap.managed-kafka-poc.asia-south2.managedkafka.managed-kafka-445110.cloud.goog/10.190.0.17 (channelId=-1) (Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism OAUTHBEARER)   [org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,043 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,047 ERROR  ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (bootstrap.managed-kafka-poc.asia-south2.managedkafka.managed-kafka-445110.cloud.goog/10.190.0.17:9092) failed authentication due to: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism OAUTHBEARER   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,049 WARN   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed due to authentication error   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism OAUTHBEARER
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,057 INFO   ||  App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,057 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,058 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited. Call: fetchMetadata
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,058 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Timed out 2 remaining operation(s) during close.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,065 INFO   ||  [Principal=:sub]: Expiring credential re-login thread has been interrupted and will exit.   [org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.expiring.ExpiringCredentialRefreshingLogin]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,066 INFO   ||  Metrics scheduler closed   [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,067 INFO   ||  Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter   [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,067 INFO   ||  Metrics reporters closed   [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | 2024-12-20 18:01:26,068 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli]
debezium-connect-managed-new  | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
my docker-compose.yaml file:
ervices:
debezium-connect-managed-new:
image: debezium/connect:3.0.0.Final
container_name: debezium-connect-managed-new
environment:
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: bootstrap.managed-kafka-poc.asia-south2.managedkafka.managed-kafka-445110.cloud.goog:9092
GROUP_ID: debezium-group
CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: OAUTHBEARER
CONNECT_SASL_OAUTHBEARER_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required
clientId=""
clientSecret="cliendSecret"
oauth.refresh.token="token"
oauth.grant.type="refresh_token"
sasl.login.callback.handler.class="org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler"
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url.file="/etc/kafka/kafka_client_jaas.txt"
unsecuredLoginStringClaim_sub="sub"
unsecuredLoginStringClaim_scope="scope";'
volumes:
- ./kafka_client_jaas_token.txt:/etc/kafka/kafka_client_jaas.txt
ports:
- "8084:8083"
networks:
- dev_net
restart: unless-stopped
networks:
dev_net:
driver: bridge
This file /kafka_client_jaas_token.txt: has JWT token which i am generating via this curl
curl --location 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'client_id=764086051850-6qr4p6gpi6hn506pt8ejuq83di341hur.apps.googleusercontent.com' 
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=d-FL95Q19q7MQmFpd7hHD0Ty' 
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=1//0glwSxrRN_NvzCgYIARAAGBASNwF-L9IrDuwgfFRqJLMtBLcmeguSvNwJbqXsq-QRYh3YFnhgAvT3M5NGoTHOqbuAjqbaq8YaqTc' 
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token'
I tried method given by google documentations but this doesn't work out
https://cloud.google.com/managed-service-for-apache-kafka/docs/authentication-kafka#gcloud
I tried with authentication method :

PLAIN
OAUTHBEARER


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
